# separator not displayed properly for custom table view cells in ios

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

In the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm7zS.png) I have created my custom table view cell. But I am not getting the separator for alternate cells. Please suggest me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has default `Separator Inset` equals to 15 - just change it to 0 in your storyboard or xib file.

[image]

UPD: If you don't see you lines in iPhone6+ simulator - thats because of big resolution, try it on the device, or press `Cmd + 1`, `Cmd + 2`, `Cmd + 3` and so on to change zoom, while your simulator app is active

Comment: Yes I am using 0 for both left and right side. But the problem is not with the insets. I am not getting the separator for all my rows. In the attached image you can see that some rows are not separated with the separator.

Comment: @Satheshkumar see my update, I think, I understood your problem

Comment: Hi katleta3000. Thanks for your quick response. Yes it is displayed if i zoom in. Thanks a lot. As I am new to this community I dont have enough reputation to up vote your answer.

Comment: @Satheshkumar you're welcome